# Running ruby files from $PATH in Eshell

Tags: microsoft-windows, eshell, path, ruby

I'm trying to find a way to run `.rb` files that are in the `$PATH` in Eshell by following the solution [here](http://help-gnu-emacs.gnu.narkive.com/JvqUGb2i/eshell-win32-executable-files). I added `".rb"` to `exec-suffixes`, set `eshell-force-execution` to `t` and customized `eshell-interpreter-alist` like this:

```
Regexp: \.rb
String: c:/programs/rails/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
```

But when I run an .rb file in eshell I get an error:

`c:\programs\rails\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- bill.rb (LoadError)`

However it works if I run the file in the directory where it is located or with a full path.
Seems like it is necessary to make interpreter in `eshell-interpreter-alist` expand `bill.rb` to its full path somehow to make it work, but I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it exists in your $PATH? `M-x getenv PATH`

Comment: `which` returns the full path to the file. Your suggestion reveals no errors either.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change `eshell-interpreter-alist` to

`Regexp: \.rb
Interpreter: eshell-run-ruby-command-from-path`

And provide the following function to make it work

`(defun eshell-run-ruby-command-from-path (args)
  (eshell-named-command "ruby.exe" (list (eshell-search-path args))))`